# usage of the semicolon in F#, different behaviors

Tags: f#

I have the following line:

```
| ResponseTableTypes.Order ->
    orderProcessor.ProcessEvent action message
    orderEvent.Trigger()
```

since I have a lot of entries, for layout reasons, I did:

```
| ResponseTableTypes.Order -> orderProcessor.ProcessEvent action message; orderEvent.Trigger()
```

all good, but then I added some return type:

```
| ResponseTableTypes.Order -> let s = orderProcessor.ProcessEvent action message; orderEvent.Trigger(s)
```

that will not compile, I get:

> The block following this 'let' is unfinished. Every code block is an expression and must have a result. 'let' cannot be the final code element in a block. Consider giving this block an explicit result.

so, if I break down the line again:

```
| ResponseTableTypes.Order ->
    let s = orderProcessor.ProcessEvent action message
    orderEvent.Trigger(s)
```

then it obviously works again

what is happening with the let/semicolon combination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Starting with `| ResponseTableTypes.Order -> let s = orderProcessor.ProcessEvent action message; orderEvent.Trigger(s)`, let's reduce irrelevancies such as tables, orders, and events:

```
let result =
    let s = expression; action
```

Now let's ascribe simple values to the names, so that apart from the issue we want to identify, it should compile.

```
let x =
    let y = 0; 0
    // FS0588 the block following this let is unfinished.
    // FS0020 The result of this expression has type 'int' and is implicitly ignored.
```

Now that we have a clean question, we can start to answer it, but this is the easy part. `let y = 0; 0` is equivalent to `let y = (0;0)` and so the first `0` is being ignored, and since `let y = ...` is an incomplete expression which does not return anything, there is nothing to ascribe to `x`.

There is an antique syntax `let y = 0 in 0` which does allow merging multiple lines with `let`s into one.

Comment: "antique syntax" lol. As an OCaml developer I take offense! :P

Comment: OCaml is based on ML which was created in 1973 and it had the let x in y syntax so that is at least 46 years old :). In F# I do use the let x in y syntax from time to time.